# Field theoretic terminology

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, terminology

What is the standard name (if any) given to a field in which every element $x$ can be expressed as $a^2$ or $-a^2$ for appropriate $a$? I have seen such fields termed in one respectable set of notes on geometric algebra as ‘’spin fields” but searching for the term online seems to lead only to physics-related topics.

Comment: Cf. [Euclidean field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_field)

Comment: Thanks. But Euclidean fields are ordered. Anything which doesn’t require ordering?

Comment: I've seen the term [quadratically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_closed_field) before.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it! Euclidean is the right answer, and the ordering shouldn't concern you. In a Euclidean field, the ordering is defined by saying positive iff square, so there is no extra structure assumed.